# TYPO3: add maxitems = 1 to an image selection for a backend module

Tags: typo3, fal

I use the following code to make an image selection available in the backend:
([TYPO3 docs - inline - File Abstraction Layer](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/10.4/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline.html#file-abstraction-layer))

```
'image' => [
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.images',
    'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
        'image',
        [
            'appearance' => [
                'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference'
            ],
            // custom configuration for displaying fields in the overlay/reference table
            // to use the image overlay palette instead of the basic overlay palette
            'overrideChildTca' => [
                'types' => [
                    '0' => [
                        'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ],
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_TEXT => [
                        'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
    ),
],
```

I want to limit the selection to 1 item which should be:
[TYPO3 dosc - maxitems option](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/8.6/Feature-78899-TCAMaxitemsOptional.html)

```
image => [
    'config' => [
        'maxitems' => 1,
    ],
],
```

I cannot find how to add that ... all I tried gives errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, you just have to find the matching part of documentation...

[File abstraction layer (FAL)](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Fal/UsingFal/Tca.html#tca-definition)

> The API call is \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(). The first argument is the name of the current field, the second argument is an override configuration array, (...)

So it should do with overriding a part of the generated configuration by:

```
'image' => [
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.images',
    'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
        'image',
        [
            'maxitems' => 1
        ]
    )
]
```